# Why tosyl group is better leaving group than benzenesulphonyl group?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I read a book on organic chemistry that stated that tosyl is better leaving group than benzenesulphonyl  group, but it gave no reason for comparison. 
I think that benzenesulphonyl should be better leaving group since methyl group in tosyl should be destabilizing for the anion due to its +I and +R effect. 
I tried searching on the internet but it was of no help.
Please give a reason why tosyl is better leaving group.

Answer (score 0):

First of all CH3 group dosent show +R effect in benzene system .
Secondly Inductive effect wears out over distance and has maximum range of 4 carbons.The charge is delocalised on carbons which are unaffected by this effect so ultimately it has no role in destabilising the anion

Comment: Doesn't methyl group show +R by hyper conjugation.

Comment: Hyperconjugation and resonnance are two different things    http://www.askiitians.com/forums/Organic-Chemistry/21/39702/hyperconjugation.htm

Comment: moreover if the methyl group wants to hyperconjugate,the carbon on the benzene system bonded to it would become pentavalent

Comment: Well, I was trying to say that methyl groups reduces the electron deficiency on benzene ring by hyper conjugation thereby reducing the -I effect of benzene ring.

Comment: please do explain how it can hyperconjugate @nikola

Comment: As i said in my earlier comment,if the methyl group hyperconjugates,the carbon it is attached to would have to be pentavalent..Hopefully you understood,pls do accept the answer if you did

Comment: You can search the internet to see the hyper conjugating structures. I will post the link in a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55264/discussion-between-quarkylittlething-and-nikola).

Comment: This has toluene's hyper conjugating structures http://www.chemvista.org/hyperconjugation.html